# iPhone app database

Tags: iphone, sqlite

So I can access a read-only SQLite database inside an iPhone / iPod app (Objective-C), but I'm writing a new app that will have a writable database.  Obviously, the r/w file has to be in the user-writable directory.  My question is, should I ship an empty database with the application and copy it over to the r/w location, or create the r/w database on the fly the first time the app launches?

Comment: Ship a blank one in package resources, copy to the Documents folder on the first run. Cheaper than running (and maintaining) a schema creation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either, but it will be much easier (and less error prone) for you to create an empty database, put it in your bundle and then do this in your AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (void)prepareDatabase
{
    //add Database Versioning check to see if the resources database is newer
    // generally as simple as naming your database with a version on the end

    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"/YOURDATABASE.s3db"];
    if(![filemanager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]) {
        //Database doesn't exist yet, so we copy it from our resources
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/YOURDATABASE.s3db"];
        if([filemanager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:databasePath error:nil]) {
            NSLog(@"Database Copied from resources");           
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Database copy FAILED from %@ to %@",defaultDBPath,databasePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method call this:

```
[self prepareDatabase];
```

Comment: This is correct (+1). To be even more bulletproof you could copy to a different file name then rename. That way the final operation to create your empty database ready for use is atomic.